# AngularJs Windows Intranet User

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, intranet

Using ASP.Net Web API service I can get the current windows user using the following.

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
 {
    public string Get()
    {
        var id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        return id.Name;
    }
 }
```

My question is how can I find the current user logged in a angularjs controller without having to call the web api service?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a GET request in AngularJS to get data you have through a service in .NET?

Comment: I am looking for recommendation on how to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Unome I was trying this 'public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
        }
    }' so that the angular controller could get the user name but the Name property is always null.

Comment: Please place an example of your code in your question so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
   myApp.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {


      $scope.getUserData = function(){
          $http({method: 'GET', url: '/URLtoResourceInWebService'}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             //use the data of your User object
          }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             // called asynchronously if an error occurs
             // or server returns response with an error status.
          });
      }


   }); //End of Controller
```

Here is a real simple example of how to hit an endpoint in Angular and get back a resource from a WebService. I would actually suggest extracting out your API calls however into a service rather than using the "$http" because then you centralize them in one place, and if you switch API's your code doesn't break all over. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks but my question is more about how to find out who is currently logged in with angular.  Not how to get information from a service into angular.

Comment: Hmm, with what I've done I've always just stored the resource for my Username somewhere on my $scope, and then I can just access the JSON object. Not quite sure how your stuff is working. If you can provide more code maybe I can help better.